# How to read file in UTF-8 mode

Tags: utf-8, lua

I have some trouble. I had never work with LUA before.

I have simple file with the next content:

```
«Counting Stars» ― OneRepublic
```

So I wrote the next code for read this file:

```
BotSite = ""

local open = io.open

local function read_file(path)
    local file = open(path, "r") 
    if not file then return nil end
    local content = file:read "*all" 
    file:close()
    return content
end

BotSay = UserFrom .. ", " ..read_file("D:/Snip/Snip.txt")
```

After executing that code, I getting:

```
nickname, Â«Counting StarsÂ» â OneRepublic
```

As i right understand it UTF-8 problem. How to fix it?

---

So I got interest answer:

> The official *unmodified* Lua library does not support UTF-8 on
>   Windows.  Most SDKs and game engines (such as Corona) modify the
>   native Lua library code to add UTF-8 support to it on Windows. 
>   (Technically the issue is that Lua calls the Win32 char* APIs which
>   only support ANSI text encoding, not UTF-8, and you have to transcode
>   the UTF-8 string in Lua to UTF-16 and call Win32's wchar* APIs
>   instead.)

Comment: What OS? Your terminal probably is not set up as UTF-8.

Comment: I use Windows 10. This code executing in other program. It bot for twitch. This program support "lua script files"

Comment: Colonel Thirty Two, I just have the script file https://yadi.sk/d/ShvzqZMivQSpV for executing

Comment: Open with binary mode

Comment: moteus, if i open it in binary mode, this problem the same. And more one problem: it file can't be rewrite. Sorry your file using by other app lalala

Comment: As I right did, binary mode it instead **open(path, "r")** I need to use  **open(path, "rb")**

Comment: Lua doesn't use encodings; all strings exist as an array of eight-character bytes. Whatever you are using to control the output has a problem with the encoding. What are you using to control output?

Comment: RyanSquared, In fact, I use special program for twitch. I no have access to executing program. I just have LUA file. The program written on c# as i know. I must assign to *BotSay* variable a string.

Comment: Lua does not call any Win32 API. (only for load library but it is in `package` labrary code not in Lua itself). So answer is your host aplication does not support UTF-8 API on Windows.